# How to use NodeJS child_process in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, child-process, spawn

When I try to execute a child_process `spawn` in interactive mode `node -i` it works, no problem.
E.g.

```
node -i
> const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');
> spawn("ls", ["-lah"]);
```

A child process is created, everything's fine.

When I try to use child_process in typescript like

```
...
import spawn from "node:child_process";
...
  
spawn("ls", ["-lah"]);
```

it doesn't work.

VSCode highlights the last line `spawn(...)` with the error message

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("node:child_process")' has no call signatures.
```

When I build the code I get the same message

```
src/main.ts:20:3 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("node:child_process")' has no call signatures.
```

It doesn't matter which command I try to call in `spawn(...)`, I tried several, always the same error.
How do I use child_process in typescript correctly?

Comment: Put the spawn in curly braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need the curly braces, or else you're importing the whole package as `spawn`, which isn't callable

```
...
import { spawn } from "node:child_process";
...
  
spawn("ls", ["-lah"]);
```

Comment: Ah damn, I searched the internet up and down and then it's such an obvious thing. Tank you